# Is it necessary to make pointer Null when there is no use of it at the end in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

Is it necessary to make pointer `NULL` when the pointer is no more in use. For example

```
Foo *foo=new Foo();
//code to be processed by pointer foo

/*end of code*/
delete foo;
foo=NULL;     //the point which i am asking
```

My questions are:

- What kind of effects i.e., good or bad it can cause to the program?
- What will happen if we don't use this?

Thanks in advance for clearing my points.

Comment: You mean `foo=nullptr;`, not `foo=NULL;` because `NULL` has no sense in C++

Comment: If the pounter is not used any more, there is no reason to make it null. But you should not be using raw pointers anyway.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. "you should not be using raw pointers anyway" I cannot agree. One should not be using owning raw pointers. There are still use cases for raw pointers and then it is still good practice to have them either valid or null pointer

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What?  NULL is defined in the C++ standard (it's a stub to the C definition).

Comment: Its not necessary, but is good practice. Using a deleted pointer is a common bug, and having it caught immediately (due to null dereference) makes catching and debugging it much easier.

Comment: @idclev463035818 well Inwould use non-nullable smart pointers by default, see "the billion dollar mistake".

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I heard about it, maybe I should read more (i mean of course I didnt want to advocate usage of raw pointers)

Comment: In modern C++, best practice is to not use the `new` and `delete` keywords, since there are higher-level tools for doing almost everything they can do but more simply and more safely.

Comment: @aschepler I am using visual studio enterprise 2017 for this.

Answer (score 2):

No. You don't need to assign `nullptr` to a pointer variable if you are no longer going to use it.

*But* if you need to detect whether or not the pointer variable refers to a *valid* object at some later point in the program, then setting it to `nullptr` after you `delete` it, and later testing for that is the most simple way to do that.

Comment: I can't agree with your last sentence. It's a terrible way to do that because it won't somehow magically set other copies of the pointer to `nullptr`.

Comment: @David of course it will not. I never claimed it would. But it will let you test *this* variable. I never claimed it would let you do anything else. Feel free to add your own answer :)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "detect whether or not the pointer variable is valid at some later point". I honestly can't think of anything that phrase could mean that renders your claim accurate. If you can test the variable, it's valid. If you mean whether it points to an existent object, the test won't work for the reason I explained.

Comment: @David Better after the edit? If not, feel free to edit yourself. I think you perfectly well know what I intend to convey.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. It's still wrong. That won't help if some other piece of code called `delete` on its copy of the pointer. It's not a generally recommended practice precisely because you can only use it in narrow cases where you happen to know for sure that it will work. There is, in general, no simple way to know if the value of a pointer is still valid other than carefully tracking it in a code-dependent way. Setting to `nullptr` without careful analysis is a bad habit that has the unfortunate consequence of leading to thinking it always works and making mistakes.

Comment: @David that part of my answer is *only* about the narrow case where you use *this specific* variable later (it would commonly be a member variable) and you need to know if it holds a valid value or not.